# error while accessing method of class - python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I have uploaded a simple package to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi .
I have followed following steps,

```
python setup.py register -r https://testpypi.python.org/pypi

python setup.py sdist upload -r https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
```

Then downloaded this package to locally and executed setup.py with install command. ( package url https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/printlistonlynew/0.1 )
And then package was installed successfully.

Here is structure and code for package,

```
│   setup.py
│
└───listprint
        stack.py
        __init__.py
```

contents of stack.py are,

```
class Xyz:

    def __init__(self,):
        pass

    def printList(self):
        print [i for i in range(0,10)]
```

When I tried to import the method printList from the installed package it give me error ,

```
AttributeError: Xyz instance has no attribute 'printList'
```

Here is code I am trying to execute,

```
from listprint import stack
x=stack.Xyz()
print x
print x.printList()
```

What wrong I am doing here ? Any namespace problem ?

Comment: Please show the code that tries to do that import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded your file, and you have indentation issues. Because you're mixing tabs and spaces, Python is considering `printList` as nested *inside* `__init__`.

Stick to spaces only.